# Add multiple products into line_items - Stripe & React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I'm facing a problem with my code, I have to add multiple items into line_items data from stripe.. I already tried to add the things that I need (price and quantity) into a new array, but I failed when I did it..

could you guys please help me with my code?

Code below \/

[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrl8S.png)

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gaiu.png)

[Server Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHXxa.png)

I already tried to find some solution on google and stack overflow, but I couldn't figure out how to fix my code

Comment: Could you please copy/paste your code into formatted code blocks instead of linking to screenshots?  It's hard to debug if we cannot see the all of the code together in one place.  Still separate out the sections like you are doing but with actual text please. It'll help us help you. Also, where are you setting the value for `items` prior to creating the Checkout Session?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.